# Private members (specifially pointers) cannot be accessed when operator << is overloaded

Tags: c++

```
#include<climits>

class Int
{
    int *i, p;

    public:

    Int(){
        i = new int;
    }

    Int operator=(int a){
        *i = a , p = 7;
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Int& dt);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Int& int_obj){
         // os << int_obj.p << '\n'; // accessible
         os << int_obj.*i << '\n'; // ERROR i was not declared int his scope
        return os; 
}

int main(){
    Int i;
    i = 5;
    std::cout << i;
}
```

In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Int&)’:

error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope

Why can't i access my pointer variables from the reference of this object ?

Comment: You want `*int_obj.i`, not `int_obj.*i`.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

`os << *int_obj.i << '\n';`

`int_obj.*i` is meaningless, you're asking to use a member `*i` of `int_obj`, which is not available

Also, suggested: [Precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), for why you don't need `()` for dereferencing

Answer (score 1):

You've misplaced the dereference operator. You wanted this:

```
os << *int_obj.i << '\n';
```

That is, dereference `int_obj.i`.

The expression `int_obj.*i` applies the operator `.*` to `int_obj` and a pointer-to-member `i`. And since there's no such `i` declared, the compiler complains.

Comment: Still, strange diagnostic.

Comment: Oh, wait, no it's not - the pointer-to-member would need to be local I guess.